# Alternative ways of doing Item groupings from an item list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Do anyone have any suggestions how can I better refine / if there are any ways that I can derive the following results:

```
import itertools
item_list = ['aaa:sampleA1', 'ccc:sampleC2', 'ccc:sampleC1']
grouping = {}

for cat_name, item in itertools.groupby(sorted(item_list), lambda x: x.split(":")[0]):
    grouping[cat_name] = list(item)

print grouping # {'aaa': ['aaa:sampleA1'], 'ccc': ['ccc:sampleC1', 'ccc:sampleC2']}
```

I am trying to sort and perform item categorization based off from an item list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the item list and append each value to the sub-list according to the key instead:

```
grouping = {}
for item in item_list: # or sorted(item_list) if you do need the sub-lists to be sorted
    key, value = item.split(':')
    grouping.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

`grouping` becomes:

```
{'aaa': ['sampleA1'], 'ccc': ['sampleC2', 'sampleC1']}
```